# How to configre Create React Apps default Service Worker to cache assets that are not in react src Context (public Folder)?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, service-worker, workbox-webpack-plugin

today I tried the ServiceWorker of Create React App and everything is cached except the Favicon of my Page which is defined in public/img/favicon.ico, so when the Page is Offline the Favicon disapears and Connection Error is displayed in Console, so does anyone has experience how to configure webpage Plugin of the Service worker to cache this too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a CRA project [here](https://github.com/jamessouth/directory).  I don't precache my favicon, I let a default handler runtime cache it, but I do precache a fallback image and you should be able to do the same to precache your favicon.

CRA creates a default sw which I don't think I touched.  To get more control I use workbox in a sw-addendum file that I append to the default sw in the build.  In the addendum you can precache what you need and set up routes, etc.

see [package.json](https://github.com/jamessouth/directory/blob/master/package.json) for postdeploy script

```
"postdeploy": "cp src/face.69232788.jpg docs/face.69232788.jpg && cat src/swAddendum.js >> docs/service-worker.js",
```

sw-addendum [here](https://github.com/jamessouth/directory/blob/master/src/swAddendum.js)

```js
workbox.precaching.precache([
  './face.69232788.jpg',
]);
```

Comment: Yes I get how to do Workbox mamual but cra uses workox webpack generatesw to completely generate the sw and cannot even add files to precache to the ones in webpack config, so I tried something like you to create my own impl of sw.js but then Webpack doesn't find it with InjectManifest Plugin of Workbox

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you here, it sounds like everything is cached except the favicon, if you do what I did you should be able to precache it.

Comment: Yeah I needed to understand Workbox and now I get what you where talking about so thank you